# Creating build and publish script for .net Application using powershell

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell, build, msbuild

I am new to power shell, I am trying to write a power shell script to build and publish the c#/.net application(Web). I have tried below code to generate build-

```
$projectFileAbsPath = .csproj path
$msbuild $projectFileAbsPath /t:rebuild /p:PlatformTarget=x86 /fl /p:outputpath=C:\test
```

by executing above line i am only getting dll of the project in destination folder. Supporting\Referenced dll's and related artifacts are missing.
Please help me understand where i am getting wrong and what additional things i need to do. Also, do i need any build configuration file .If yes, let me know if there is any sample posted on internet.